# Unix - "xargs" - output "in the middle" (not at the end!)

Tags: unix, g++, xargs

example use of `xargs` application in Unix can be something like this:

```
ls | xargs echo
```

which is the same as (let's say I have `someFile` and `someDir/` in the working directory):

```
echo someFile someDir
```

so `xargs` take its input and place it *at the end* of the next command (here at the end of echo).

But sometimes I want `xargs` to place its input somewhere *in the middle* of next command.

For example:

```
find . -type f -name "*.cpp" -print | xargs g++ -o outputFile
```

so if I had in the current directory files `a.cpp`, `b.cpp`, `c.cpp` the output would be the same as with the command:

```
g++ -o outputFile a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
```

but I want to have something like this:

```
g++ a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp -o outputFile
```

Is there a way to do it?

P.S.: I need it in some cases, because e.g.:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -o outputFile `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-2.4` a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
```

doesn't work but this one works fine:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp -o outputFile `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-2.4`
```

Answer (score 18):

To answer the original question asked in the title of how to use `xargs` with the input in the middle rather than the end:

```
$ echo a b c | xargs -I {} echo before {} after
before a b c after
```

This replaces `{}` in the command with the piped output. There are some subtle differences between BSD and GNU xargs described below:

### BSD xargs (e.g. on MacOS/Darwin, freebsd)

Use `-I REPLACE`, which will replace the string `REPLACE` (or whatever you pass) in the command. For example:

```
$ echo a b c | xargs -I {} echo before {} after
before a b c after
$ echo a b c | xargs -I REPLACE echo before REPLACE after
before a b c after
$ echo 'a
> b
> c' | xargs -L1 -I {} echo before {} after
before a after
before b after
before c after
```

The [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE&format=html) describes the option:

```
 -I replstr
     Execute utility for each input line, replacing one or more occur-
     rences of replstr in up to replacements (or 5 if no -R flag is
     specified) arguments to utility with the entire line of input.
     The resulting arguments, after replacement is done, will not be
     allowed to grow beyond replsize (or 255 if no -S flag is speci-
     fied) bytes; this is implemented by concatenating as much of the
     argument containing replstr as possible, to the constructed argu-
     ments to utility, up to replsize bytes.  The size limit does not
     apply to arguments to utility which do not contain replstr, and
     furthermore, no replacement will be done on utility itself.
     Implies -x.
```

### GNU xargs (e.g. on Linux)

```
$ echo a b c | xargs -i echo before {} after
before a b c after
$ echo a b c | xargs -I THING echo before THING after
before a b c after
```

Use either the `-I REPLACE` or the the `-i` argument, which [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) describes:

```
   -I replace-str
          Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments
          with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do
          not terminate input items; instead the separator is the
          newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.

   -i[replace-str], --replace[=replace-str]
          This option is a synonym for -Ireplace-str if replace-str is
          specified.  If the replace-str argument is missing, the effect
          is the same as -I{}.  This option is deprecated; use -I
          instead.
```

The `-L 1` on `-I` means that it will execute each of the input in a separate command:

```
$ echo "a
> b
> c" | xargs -I THING echo before THING after
before a after
before b after
before c after
```

Comment: Regarding the last sentence in parentheses: `xargs -i` has exactly the same effect `xargs -I` w.r.t. line breaks. The only difference between `-i` and `-I` is, that `-i` defaults to `{}` for the replacement string, while `-I` does not have any default.

Comment: @ElmarZander Indeed, thank you! Not sure what I was thinking 6 years ago, but I wasn't able to produce a difference, even on a very old docker image from that vintage. I removed that sentence.

Answer (score 6):

If your version of xargs doesn't include the `-I` feature, an alternative is to write a little shell script containing the command you want to execute:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec i586-mingw32msvc-g++ "$@" -o outputFile...
```

Then use xargs to run that:

```
find . -type f -name "*.cpp" -print | xargs my_gcc_script
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `xargs` for this.  Just use:

```
g++ `find . -type f -name '*.cpp'` -o outputFile
```

Comment: I'd say use $() over back ticks, but it works so I can't complain.

Comment: I used backtick because he didn't say what shell he was using, and backtick works with more of them (e.g. tcsh).

Comment: You really shouldn't do this. Spaces will break this.

Comment: This also doesn't work in the scenario (which is one of the things `xargs` is made for!) when you have more arguments than can fit on a single command line (`getconf ARG_MAX` for the total combined size of all environment variables and command-line arguments permitted for a single process). Granted, `g++` will misbehave in that case either way, but Q&A entries get used beyond the scope of the single person who first asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ would be a solution too:

```
find . -type f -name "*.cpp" -print | parallel -Xj1 g++ {} -o outputFile
```

The *.cpp must fit in a single line (~128 KB).

Comment: If I use `-X` without `-j1`, it gets split over multiple commands, one command per item piped in.  With `-j1` (one process) it works for me.  I'd also suggest `find -print0` and `parallel -0`.