# Final arguments for xargs

Tags: xargs

I want to do something similar to this:

```
find . -type f | xargs cp dest_dir
```

But `xargs` will use `dest_dir` as initial argument, not as final argument. I would like to know:

1. Is it possible to specify final arguments to `xargs`?
2. Any other alternative to achieve the same result?

### EDIT

A possible, but cumbersome alternative is this:

```
find . -type f | while read f ; do echo cp $f dest_dir ; done
```

I do not like this because dozens of `cp` processes will be started.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`-I` option replaces occurrences of `replace-str` in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.

For example:

```
find . -type f | xargs -I file cp file dest_dir
```

Should solve your problem.

More details in the following tutorial:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/

Especially the part about `{}` as the argument list marker

Comment: However, `-I` implies `-L 1`, that means it is still suffering from the problem OP tried to avoid (*"I do not like this because dozens of cp processes will be started."*)

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to achieve something slightly different using xargs and pdfunite, and launching multiple instances of pdfunite didn't cut it for me.

I was essentially trying to do:

```
$ ls -v *.pdf | xargs pdfunite <files> all-files.pdf
```

with `all-files.pdf` being the final argument to pdfunite. But `xargs` with `-I` didn't give me what I wanted:

```
$ ls -v *.pdf | xargs -I {} pdfunite {} all-files.pdf
```

This just gave me a result which had `all-files.pdf` being the last file output by `ls`. And that's because multiple instances of pdfunite were launched.

I finally just gave up on `xargs`, and went with the following simpler construct, which sufficed for my purposes:

```
$ pdfunite `ls -v *.pdf` all-files.pdf
```

Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: Backtick/`$()` expansion has all sorts of nasty side effects.

Comment: Also, avoid parsing with `ls`.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution, use `-t` when the command supports it. `cp` and `mv` have it.

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t dest_dir --
find -type f -exec cp -t dest_dir -- {} +
```

As noted by [o11c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45684006/445221), using `xargs` in this case is not necessary.

Also notice that I used `-print0` and `-0` in my first example. Using `'\0'` as a delimiter avoids trouble with filenames having newlines with them.

Everyone here also didn't suggest to at least use `-d '\n'`.  `xargs` splits spaces (not just newlines) when it is not specified.

```
find -type f | xargs -d '\n' cp -t dest_dir --
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion for GNU `cp` and `mv`, but I don't think it's portable. For example, BSD utilites (at least the ones on the Mac OS X machines I manage) do not support the -t flag. (Only the `-i` and `-f` flags are POSIX).

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you don't need to use `xargs` (for example, `find . -type f -exec cp {} dest_dir +`). But just in case you do ...

---

Simply save the below script in `$PATH`, and use it like:

```
find . -type f | xargs final-args dest_dir -- cp
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: final-args 4 5 6 -- echo 1 2 3
final=()
for arg
do
    shift
    if [[ "$arg" = "--" ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    final+=("$arg")
done
exec "$@" "${final[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel [handles this better than xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017627/411282), avoiding the workarounds above, if you have that available.

http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/