# how to take standard input as the value of a command's option?

Tags: linux, attr, xargs

For example I want to take the content of file named "comment" to be the value of setattr's -v option, something like

```
cat comment | setfattr -n user.comment -v -  filewanttotaged
```

but this does not work, neither do

```
cat comment | xargs setfattr -n user.comment -v - filewantedtotaged
```

For the latter case, the content is treated as file arugment for setfattr, instead of value of option -v

So how to do this job? Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix - "xargs" - output "in the middle" (not at the end!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383170/unix-xargs-output-in-the-middle-not-at-the-end)

Answer (score 2):

you can use xargs, but make sure its arguments are not at the end, but after your "-v" option:

```
cat comment | xargs -i setfattr -n user.comment -v {} filewantedtotaged
```

Comment: Thank you! So the key here is to add -i to xargs.

Comment: Another question is that if there is "\n" in the comment file, only the first line can go into the value of option -v. So there must be some way to tell xargs to escape that end of line, I will check. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Yes, add -0 to xargs will do

Comment: you're welcome... if this answered your question, please accept the answer to mark that the question has been solved.